# Topology closedness

Tags: general-topology

Let $Int(Y)$ denote the *interior* of $Y,$ and let $\overline{X}$ denote the *closure* of $X.$ How do you show that

$$Int(Y) \cup Int(Z) \subseteq  Int(Y \cup Z)?$$ Can you give an example?

I know this is the complement of $\overline {Y\cap Z} \subset \overline{Y} \cap \overline{Z}$ but it's difficult for me to understand the relationship between these two.

Comment: What is your definition of Int$(Y)$? Recall that Int$(Y)$ is the largest open set containing $Y$ and proceed...

Comment: These proofs are highly context dependent. What are your definitions of open and closed sets?

Comment: Given: X is a topological space and Y, Z $\subset$ X

Comment: @user336258: Great! Then the result is obvious using my last comment.Can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

If $\tau$ is the topology of $X$,
$$x\in Int Y\cup Int Z\implies\exists U(U\in\tau\wedge x\in U\wedge (U\subset Y\vee U\subset Z))$$
$$\implies \exists U(U\in\tau\wedge x\in U\wedge U\subset Y\cup Z)\implies x\in Int(Y\cup Z)$$

Comment: I'm aware of that. Writing the full solution in a formal language, with no explanation, is meant to be a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V(Y)$ denote the family of all open subsets of the set $Y.$ (This is not a standard notation.)

(1).Def'n: Int$(Y)=\cup  V(Y).$

(2). Since a union of a family of open sets is open, Int$(Y)$ is open. Since every member of $V(Y)$ is a subset of Y we have Int$(Y)=\cup V(Y)\subset Y.$ So Int$(Y)$ is an open subset of Y. Therefore  by (1) we have Int$(Y)\in V(Y).$

(3). If $W$ is an open subset of $Y$ then $W\in V(Y) \implies W\subset \cup V(Y)=$Int$(Y)\in V(Y).$ So Int$(Y)$ is the largest open subset of $Y.$ That is, any member of $V(Y)$ is a subset of Int$(Y).$

(4). Int$(X)$ and Int$(Y)$ are open sets with Int$(X)\subset X$ and Int$(Y)\subset Y. $ So Int$(X) \cup$Int$(Y)$ is an open subset of $X \cup Y .$ That is, Int$(X)\cup$Int$(Y)\in V(X\cup Y). $ Therefore by (3) we have $$ \text {Int}(X)\cup \text {Int}(Y)\subset \text {Int}(X\cup Y).$$

Examples.[1]. In the space $\mathbb R$ let $X=\mathbb Q$ and $Y=\mathbb R$ \ $X.$ Then  Int$(X)=$Int$(Y)=\emptyset$ ................but Int$(X\cup Y)=$Int$(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R.$

[2].In $\mathbb R$ let $X=(0,1]$ and $Y=[1,2).$ Then Int$(X)\cup$Int$(Y)=(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ ........................and Int$(X\cup Y)=(0,2).$